# Nginx Virtual hosts?

Tags: nginx, virtualhost, vhosts

I have a computer running, attempting to run nginx. I have two CName subdomains off of my main website, and I've setup my config files accordingly, but when I try to connect to it, I get a big "Cannot connect to server" error. I triple-checked my router, and port 80 is open. Also, my plex server works fine. How do I find out where the problem is so that I can fix it?

My first thought was maybe it has something to do with permissions? I'm storing files in two separate home directories. What permissions would I need to set so nginx can access them as well as the users?

```
server {
    listen 80; 
    server_name server.----.com;
    root /home/admin/public_html;
    index index.html index.htm;
}

server {
    listen 80; 
    server_name minecraft.----.com;
    root /home/minecraft/public_html;
    index index.html index.htm;
}
```

everything in /var/log/nginx is blank

`curl 127.0.0.1` gets `curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80: Connection refused`

nginx -V gets:

`nginx version: nginx/1.6.1
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-ipv6 --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_geoip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module --with-http_spdy_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.6.1/debian/modules/nginx-auth-pam --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.6.1/debian/modules/nginx-dav-ext-module --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.6.1/debian/modules/nginx-echo --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.6.1/debian/modules/nginx-upstream-fair --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.6.1/debian/modules/ngx_http_substitutions_filter_module`

output of "sudo nginx -t /etc/nginx/nginx.conf": `nginx: invalid option: "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf"`

output of "sudo netstat -pant | grep LISTEN":

`tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1511/cupsd

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:39423           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1501/Plex Plug-in [
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1224            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1627/Plex DLNA Serv
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:52718           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1757/Plex Plug-in [
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1309/X

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:32469           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1627/Plex DLNA Serv
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1143/dnsmasq

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:43094           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1671/Plex Plug-in [
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      964/sshd

tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      1511/cupsd

tcp6       0      0 :::25565                :::*                    LISTEN      1495/java

tcp6       0      0 :::32400                :::*                    LISTEN      1282/Plex Media Ser
tcp6       0      0 :::6000                 :::*                    LISTEN      1309/X

tcp6       0      0 :::32401                :::*                    LISTEN      1282/Plex Media Ser
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      964/sshd`

output of "ps -ef | grep nginx":

`root      4014     1  0 15:03 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process nginx
www-data  4015  4014  0 15:03 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
www-data  4016  4014  0 15:03 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
www-data  4017  4014  0 15:03 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
www-data  4018  4014  0 15:03 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
root     24441     1  0 14:07 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process nginx
www-data 24442 24441  0 14:07 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
www-data 24443 24441  0 14:07 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
www-data 24444 24441  0 14:07 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
www-data 24445 24441  0 14:07 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
admin    29159 28078  0 19:44 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto nginx`

output of "telnet 127.0.0.1 80":

`Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused`

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log error;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # nginx-naxsi config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

    ##
    # nginx-passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
    ##

    #passenger_root /usr;
    #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;
```

Comment: Nginx is running?  You're able to connect to it from the server itself?  Set a hosts file entry to test with.

Comment: Nginx is running but "curl: (7) Failed to connect to minecraft.----.com port 80: Connection refused" from the server after setting hosts to 192.168.0.2 minecraft.----.com

Comment: Same with 127.0.0.1 minecraft.----.com

Comment: I'm not convinced that it's the domains not working, because they work with other apps (minecraft running on minecraft.----.com, plex running on server.----.com). The problem is that I want to have a website (a map) for minecraft and server.--- to forward to :32400 essentially

Comment: I'm not suggesting it has anything to do with your domains... quite the opposite.  It's clear that Nginx isn't running.  You are running it with sudo, right?  Any server below port 1024 requires sudo, unless you're on Windows.  What do your Nginx logs say?

Comment: "~$sudo service nginx status" returns "* nginx is running", where are the logs?

Comment: anything in /var/log/nginx is blank

Comment: Add `error_log` to your config.  http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#error_log

Comment: It's been in there, pointing to /var/log/nginx/error.log, which is blank

Comment: Alright, do a `sudo service nginx stop`, then check `ps ax | grep nginx` to verify it's completely stopped.  Then just run Nginx interactively via `sudo nginx` and see if you get any error output.  If you don't, then try to access it via `curl http://127.0.0.1/` on the server.  If Nginx is indeed running via sudo, you don't have weird firewall rules,  this is your real config, and it still isn't working, then I am out of suggestions.

Comment: ps ax | grep nginx: 15661 pts/1    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto nginx --< not sure what that means

Comment: curl `http://127.0.0.1/` --> curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80: Connection refused

Comment: Do you know that your config file is even being loaded?  Have you tried creating syntax errors in it to see if you get any errors when you run Nginx?  What's the output of `nginx -V`?

Comment: I posted it in the question, check it out

Comment: And, running `nginx` interactively shows you nothing?  Did you try the config change I suggested?

Comment: `sudo nginx` does nothing, and the config change you suggested was already in place.

Comment: `sudo nginx` does nothing... as in it returns you back to the prompt?  And, if you made syntax errors in your config and nothing happened, then your config isn't being loaded.

Comment: `sudo nginx` returns back to the prompt. I made some syntax errors and got errors.

Comment: Can you provide the output of the following 4 commands?  
`sudo nginx -t /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`  
`sudo netstat -pant | grep LISTEN`  
`ps -ef | grep nginx`  
`telnet 127.0.0.1 80`

Comment: posted the output, I did notice telnet gave a refused connection... Maybe I'll look into that as a cause

Answer (score 0):

Check nginx services status, and firewall if you are using firewall for this computer.

Comment: "sudo service nginx status":"* nginx is running"

Comment: Also, no firewall setup yet, as well as connecting locally should imply you're inside the firewall?

Answer (score 0):

Can you fix this error first??

```
nginx: invalid option: "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf"
```

It could be some lines not properly ended with ;

Comment: Nope, every line that's supposed to has ; at the end, also it's the default config with nothing changed, I think.

Comment: What does the nginx error say? /var/log/nginx/error.log (for example). We will have to fix this error first because the last few lines is the "include" config to your site configs. Otherwise nginx will not run. Based on your netstat output above, 80 is not open yet by nginx.

Comment: Nothing, other than `2014/09/18 15:02:09 [emerg] 3744#0: unknown directive "uqser" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1` from something I tried hours ago to make sure I could get errors...

Comment: Can you fix this "uqser" error then? Seems to me a typo error. Probably "user" or something. If possible, can you include the content for nginx.conf as well?

Comment: What are the new errors in the log after you restarted nginx? Possible to post your nginx.conf?

Comment: There are no new errors. The nginx.conf is the default. I'll post it momentarily.

Comment: Is your web configs satisfy this requirement?? > "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf" ?  It has to be in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ directory and ends with .conf

Comment: Yes! I have no idea where my problem is :(